# Mapping slots over lists

Tags: list-manipulation, map, slot

In the meantime I'm accustomed to write special character orgies like        `D[%,#]&/@L` (to quickly fish out the coefficients of the last input with respect to the variables in list L - but I don't have to tell you that :-), but this here mixes `Slot` and `Map`. I have to lists `L1` and `L2` (of equal length 40). The function `f` shall replace the k-th element of `L1` with that of `L2`. I could simply write `f[z_]:=z/.Table[L1[[i]]->L2[[i]],{i,1,40}]` but I never become a MATHEMATICA genius that way :-) So `f[z_]:=z/.(Rule[#1,#2]/@[L1,L2])` ...nope, Slot doesn't work this way...

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear to me if you want to assign just one user-defined element from L2 to L1 or if you want to do something else.

Comment: you mean `f[z_] := z /. (Rule[#[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ Transpose[{L1, L2}])` or `f[z_] := z /. Rule @@@ Transpose[{L1, L2}]`?

Comment: Could you please clarify the desired input and *output* with an example? As it stands, I'm afraid that I can't understand what you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear[a, b, c, d, f]
l1 = {a, b}
l2 = {c, d}
rules = Thread[Rule[l1, l2]]
f[z_] := z /. rules
f[a x + b]  (* d + c x *)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're simply looking for a way to mimic what `Table[L1[[i]] -> L2[[i]], {i, 1, 40}]` does. Here are some possibilities:

```
L1 = Range[40];
L2 = 2 L1;
out1 = Table[L1[[i]] -> L2[[i]], {i, 1, 40}]
out2 = Thread[L1 -> L2]
out3 = MapThread[Rule, {L1, L2}]
out4 = Inner[Rule, L1, L2, List]
out5 = Rule @@@ Transpose[{L1, L2}]
out6 = Apply[Rule] /@ Transpose[{L1, L2}]
out1 === out2 === out3 === out4 === out5 === out6
(*True*)
```

**edit**

I just thought of another one:

```
out7 = Function[{x, y}, x -> y, Listable][L1, L2]
out7 === out1
(*True*)
```

Comment: Ah, Thread was the operator I looked for. It's sort of an argument-Map, right? Accepted for the multitude of cool curry :-)

Comment: I always think of `Thread` as a function that "pulls" lists out wherever possible (thus creating a single list of an expression that contains multiple lists). Though it's not limited to just lists: for example, you can reverse the possess again with `Thread[out2, Rule]`, in which case it "pulls" the `Rule` outside.